# Using wildcard character in bash scripting

Tags: database, linux, bash, unix, sql-loader

I'm creating a bash script that will load CSV files using SQL*Loader. Please refer to the code below:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILENAME = '/u02/logs/$(date -d '2 days ago' +%Y-%m-%d)*.csv'

# LOAD CSV FILE USING SQL*LOADER
sqlldr username/password@localhost control=control.ctl data=$FILENAME
```

However, when I try to run this script, I recieved the following error: SQL*Loader-500: Unable to open file (/u02/logs/`*`2011-11-06`*`.csv). I figure out that the problem is my * wildcard which is being interpreted as a string instead of a wildcard in bash.

Is there a way to tell the bash that my asterisk (*) is a wildcard and not a string?

Thank you for your support.

Comment: Your `$FILENAME` is using single ticks.  Haven't tried this, but have you tried using double quotes instead?

Comment: Yes. In fact, I can echo the complete $FILENAME. But when I put it in my SQL*Loader, it just simply don't work.

Comment: You'll find that the solution will be harder than you're expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i dont know about sqlldr, but i think you can try:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILENAME = '/u02/logs/$(date -d '2 days ago' +%Y-%m-%d)*.csv'

# LOAD CSV FILE USING SQL*LOADER
for fname in $(ls $FILENAME); do
    sqlldr username/password@localhost control=control.ctl data=$fname
done
```

hope it helps

Comment: Your code works like a charm! I wonder why I can't pass my file to SQL*Loader like what I did in echo. Anyway, thanks a lot! :-)

Comment: @user692533: echo isn't showing you what you think it is.  Compare the results of running `echo "$FILENAME"`, `echo $FILENAME`, and `echo data=$FILENAME`.  The first shows you what's actually in the FILENAME variable, including the literal asterisk.  In the second, the shell does filename matching before handing the argument to `echo`, so you see the matching filename instead of the asterisk.  In the last case, the shell thinks "data=" is part of the filename it should look for, doesn't find anything matching, so it leaves the literal asterisk.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try:

```
sqlldr username/password@localhost control=control.ctl data="$FILENAME"
```

Comment: Thanks buddy! I tried the double quote but the SQL*Loader still interprets it as a string. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Your use of single ticks is the problem.  Also, I'm not used to seeing bash code have spaces surrounding the equals sign.  Then again, I'm old skool.  So this is what I'd do:

```
FILENAME=/u02/logs/"$(date -d '2 days ago' +%Y-%m-%d)*.csv"
```

That should do it.  You don't need quotes around the first part since they're literal.  Only use double quotes when you need the interpreter to do do some interpolation.  Use single quotes when you don't want the interpreter to touch it.

Comment: Then again, you could start the double-quotes right after the equals sign.  It's really just a matter of style.

Comment: I tried your code. I even remove the spaces in the equal sign. When I use echo to display the value of my variable FILENAME, it displays '/u02/logs/2011-10-05_other_values.csv' which is correct. But the sql*loader still interpret it as 'u02/logs/2011/10/05*.csv'. By the way, I'm using Redhat linux

Comment: Thanks steve. But the SQL*Loader still interprets my * (asterisk) as string not a wildcard

Comment: It's looking for files matching data=u02/logs/2011/10/05*.csv, i.e. it thinks the "data=" is part of the filename. If sqlldr allows it, putting a space after `data=` would work.  Alternately, try `FILENAME_ARRAY=($FILENAME)` and then `sqlldr ... data="${FILENAME_ARRAY[@]}"`

Comment: Well, `/u02/logs/2011-10-05_other_values.csv` (the result of my bash statement) is different from `u02/logs/2011/10/05*.csv` (the lack of a leading slash character being the first dead giveaway).  Are you doing something different with FILENAME after it is created?

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
FILE=/u02/logs/$(date -d '2 days ago' +%Y-%m-%d)*.csv
```

I also note additional `*` after the `logs/` in your error message, but not in your code. Adjust accordingly.
The `*` will stay in the filename if there is no file matching the wildcard pattern. Also, be careful where more than one matching file exists.

Comment: Wow, you're really a good debugger pal! I tried removing the single qoutations.It doesn't still work. Thanks anyway :-)